# Criteria Condition on lookup table in Spring Boot Mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, lookup

I am working with Mongodb Framework... I am trying to join 2 collections using `lookup operation` in mongo aggregation as follows:

```
AggregationResults< Author> questionPaperRaw = operations.aggregate(
                    newAggregation(Author.class,
                            lookup("books","id","authorId","bookCollection") 
                                      
                           ),
                    Author.class );
```

Above works fine, my next requirement is to filter this using a criteria on books collection  "`where books.category = 'Comedy'`". I need something like below:

```
  AggregationResults< Author> questionPaperRaw = operations.aggregate(
                        newAggregation(Author.class,
                                lookup("books","id","authorId","bookCollection") ,
                                             match(Criteria.where("books.category").is("Comedy") )
                               ),
                        Author.class );
```

How to check condition on the foreign Collection "`Book`" during a lookup. Is it possible to do so?... Please Help me out...

TIA

Comment: yes, its possible.  you use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries . Spring-data doesn't provide any lookup operation for uncorelated sub queries. So we need to go with http://pingax.com/trick-convert-mongo-shell-query-equivalent-java-objects/

Comment: If you dont understand post your collections, and expected output, I will try my best